# HTML + PHP + PHPMAILER

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

obs: using translator

I have a problem on my website, every time this is sending the normal email, but it looks like an error message, in the template I got, it has a send div, as I do to skip the error-message and go to send -error

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="my-3">
                <div class="loading">Enviando</div>
                <div class="error-message"></div>
                <div class="sent-message">Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso. Muito Obrigado!</div>
              </div>
```

PHP CODE (PHPMAILER):

```
function smtp_mailer($para, $de, $de_nome, $assunto, $corpo) { 
    global $error;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();        // Ativar SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;       // Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // Autenticação ativada
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  // SSL REQUERIDO pelo GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP utilizado
    $mail->Port = 465;          // A porta 587 deverá estar aberta em seu servidor
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Username = '*';
    $mail->Password = '*';
    $mail->SetFrom("*");
    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    $mail->Body = $corpo;
    $mail->AddAddress($para);
    if(!$mail->Send()){
        echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }else {
        $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
        return false;
    }
}

 if (smtp_mailer('*', '*', $Nome, $Assunto2, $Vai)) {

    return $send;

}
if (!empty($error)){
    echo $error;
}
?>
```

IMAGE SITE:
[image]

mensagem enviada is message send in pt-br.

I need only jump for div sent-message :)

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: And please, include is as text, not an image.

Comment: I think this is not working: `$mail->Username = '*';
    $mail->Password = '*';
    $mail->SetFrom("*");` The `*` is not a valid input... At least, not for the google smtp.

Comment: i insert *, * is my infos personal, email and password....

Comment: I think you are using Ajax to call the php mailer script. Please include the ajax javascript code too in your question. I think there is where the problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

You do the error catching wrong, do this and it will work when you are prosting to the php script with a form post. This will do nothing when you are using a javascript ajax call.

```
 if(!$mail->Send()){
        echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
        $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

and

```
 if (smtp_mailer('*', '*', $Nome, $Assunto2, $Vai)) {

    echo "Done"; //dont return...

}
```

Comment: i do  this, but dont jump div error-message... 

the email is being sent normally, I just want him to stop giving this red box on the website as if it were an error ...
the loading sequence is correct, but it is returning error and not success (green background) on the web site

Comment: That problem is not in the code above, but somewhere else in your project. Please share more code.

Comment: yes, i found it, it was exactly the type of response from the server edited the html bootstrap, the 'OK' response included 'd-block' and hid the error div

THX